# Adyen's Checkout SDK integration in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, adyen

I have a react app and I want to set up adyen (payment processing API) in that. I want to use the checkout SDK (https://docs.adyen.com/developers/checkout/web-sdk )as its very simple,
I have moved the `js` logic to `componentDidMount`, but having problem loading the sdk,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/assets/js/sdk/checkoutSDK.1.6.3.min.js"></script>
```

So I can  use the below function from SDK:

```
chckt.hooks.beforeComplete = function(node, paymentData) {
   return false; // Indicates that you want to replace the default handling.
};
```

I have tried using [react-script-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-script-tag), in my React component:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className='checkout-warpper'>
               <ScriptTag type="text/javascript" src="https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/assets/js/sdk/checkoutSDK.1.9.2.min.js" />

                <div className="checkout" id="adyen-checkout">
                    {/* The checkout interface will be rendered here */}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

but still get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: chckt is not defined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `window.chckt.hooks.beforeComplete = ...` chckt is a global scope variable.

The easiest way to load external script is by using [react-async-script-loader](https://github.com/leozdgao/react-async-script-loader)

```
import React from 'react';
import scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader'

class CheckoutSDK extends React.Component {

    componentWillReceiveProps({ isScriptLoaded, isScriptLoadSucceed }) {
        if (isScriptLoaded && !this.props.isScriptLoaded) { // load finished
            if (isScriptLoadSucceed) {

                window.chckt.hooks.beforeComplete = function(node, paymentData) {
                    return false; // Indicates that you want to replace the default handling.
                };

            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return null
    }

}

export default scriptLoader('https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/assets/js/sdk/checkoutSDK.1.6.3.min.js',)(CheckoutSDK)
```

Comment: Its not maintained any more!

Comment: Take a look at [react-load-script](https://github.com/blueberryapps/react-load-script) either way you will access the chckt only from the global scope `window.chckt...`

Answer (score 1):

you can try using import ScriptLoader from 'react-script-loader-hoc'; and you can find on window.chckt.